# GA4 report on clicks by 'item_name' and 'item_brand'

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm using the GA4 measurement protocol from a PHP backend for tracking "click" events. I don't control the site where the clicks happen, so I'm creating custom tracking URLs which will be used to redirect via my PHP backend, which will in turn perform a fire-and-forget `POST https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect` before redirecting to the user's actual intended destination.

I can see the events are indeed reaching GA4 because they show up in my Events report, however I'm not able to see any dimensions like "item_name" or "item_brand". Can anyone tell me how I can see a weekly click report that is broken out by item and brand?

Comment: Do you have enabled the Enhanced Measurement setting in your GA4 property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To report on custom dimensions such as "item_name" and "item_brand" in GA4, you need to make sure of several things:

1. **Send the Parameters**: Ensure that when you're firing your events using the Measurement Protocol, you're including the `item_name` and `item_brand` parameters in your payload. You should also check the frontend.
2. **Register Parameters as Custom Dimensions**: In GA4, you must register custom event parameters before they appear in your reports. Do the following:

   - Go to the GA4 property where you want to see these custom dimensions.
   - Go to Admin or Administrator".
   - Click on Custom definition.
   - there should be "Create custom dimension" link. Click on it to register the parameter as a custom dimension. I apologise since the following photo is in Italian language:
     [image]

Remember that in GA4, data configuration is event-based, and you often need to specify what data you want to be reported on, especially when using custom parameters. Registering those custom event parameters as custom dimensions is a key step.
After creating Custom dimensions there would also be a delay of 48-72 hours.
Please have a look at the following links:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2LTMQkf8X0

For the Reporting Question you asked in comment:

**Navigating to the E-commerce Report Section in GA4:**
Log in to Google Analytics.
Navigate to the property where you've set up E-commerce tracking.
In the left-hand menu, you'll find “Monetization”. Click on it.
Under “Monetization”, you'll see reports like Overview, Ecommerce Purchase , and ... . This is where you can see your e-commerce related metrics. have a look at the following photo, of course mine is empty.
[image]

**You can also create a Custom Report (Exploration) in GA4:**

1. In the left-hand menu, click on “Explore”.
2. You’ll start with a blank form or can choose a template to start
   your exploration.
3. From here, you can add or remove metrics and
   dimensions by dragging them into the Rows and Columns of the table.
   The "Variables" panel on the left side allows you to choose
   dimensions and metrics. If you want to add dimensions like "Item
   Brand" or "Item Name", click on the "+" button in the Variables
   panel and select these dimensions from the list, like the following
   photo. Once added, you can drag them to Rows or Columns to analyze
   the data. You can further customise this view using tabs at the top
   like Table, Bar, Line, and Scatter, depending on how you want to
   visualise your data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @shila! I will try out those steps to get it working. Question for you though: are "item_name" and "item_brand" really custom dimensions? I thought these were built in as I found them in the documentation for GA4.

Comment: Also, how do I create an Event report which shows the breakdown? When I go to Reports > Library > Reports > "Events" report, I click "Dimensions" and then the "Add Dimension" dropdown. In the dropdown list, I see "Item Brand" and "Item Name" are listed under the "Ecommerce", but they are grayed out / not-selectable. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: @Shila when you say "You should also check the frontend." What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @BNazaruk, I mean you should control if the front-end developer has sent the info on the exact event happening.  for example while the user clicks on a button, the developer should call the function to trigger the GA function, and tell GA what are the info to be stored. imagine that if the user clicks on "A" item the developer should give this info to be sent. From GTM and analytics google you are just doing the settings

Comment: @skb, no those are already defined, I meant if you have customised dimensions.

Comment: @Shila and how do you control that? Like where do you have to check?

Comment: @BNazaruk you should talk to the developers team. You have the js codes right? Pass them to the developers and they should put those on head tag and body tag. Then the activation function should be called on suitable events

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem, @Shila. Front-end is not involved here. The topic starter uses the measurement protocol to send events from the backend.

Comment: @BNazaruk, sorry, that was all I knew. If you solved the problem please update us here

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
Try to not use the measurement protocol unless you're sure there's no other way. MP is messy, and GA4 certainly didn't make it better.

**Long answer:** Inspect a standard GA call to the collect endpoint even on this page. See how many dimensions are set in it even if just by default:

[image]

Now most of them are vital for reporting. They keep track of a bigger picture. GA wasn't meant to be used as a debugging tool where you can just send a few dimensions arbitrarily and expect them to be available.

The issue with using the measurement protocol and normal tracking interchangably is that you have to make sure at least the session id and the client ids are synced inbetween (**cid** and **sid** in the screenshot). You have to also carefully keep track of the referrer, document location and document path (**dl**, **dp**, **dr**) parameters on your backend. But probably even more.

While it's doable to mix the two protocols, it's rarely viable. Just too much back-end work involved.

There are better solutions to your problem.

1. A classical solution would be [UTM parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10917952?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article). They allow you to
   hardcode dimensions in the urls to be published on third party sites
   via query parameters. Once the user gets to your site with those
   parameters in the URL, the front-end GA lib will consume them and
   you will be able to report based on those parameters.
2. If you can't mutate your links on the third party site, you could use your backend to rewrite it on the fly and inject the utm params through the backend for the FE to consume.
3. Finally, UTM params tend to set the source and medium besides the campaign, platform, and other optional dimensions. That might be more than what you need. In that case, I would suggest using your backend to set a cookie (or the state, or the query params, however you communicate with the FE) for the front-end to consume. On the front-end, before sending the GA pageview, you consume the cookie and then set any fields you want in that pageview. This is a good solution too.

If you're setting custom fields (also known as event parameters), you need to make sure you're registering them in GA4 interface as custom dimensions. Don't forget that your data won't be available in reports immediately. Real time reports show it, but normal reports won't show it immediately. GA4 says for up to 48 hours for the events to show up, but it usually takes just a few hours.